# Changes in running workflows

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

I’m wondering, are there any easy ways to make changes in ongoing workflows, how are you handling with such cases. We have hundreds of running approval purchase workflows in the company and we need to add another conditional step, if the purchase quote is over let’s say 10k EURO, it needs to go additionally for management board approval. 
A new applications are working fine in the new workflow but how can we apply such changes into ongoing workflows. We'd like to avoid starting them once again.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar case, and that was a big challenge for us, unfortunately we didn't handle. Few months later, when the company had dynamically grown, we had to search for a commercial solution that would be flexible and allow us to make changes in the ongoing  processes.

We've chosen [WEBCON BPS](http://www.webcon.com), and so far honestly we are more than happy. We can really make changes in running workflows as well as really quickly build new applications.